# Casting to TV with wifi network- no internet

Tags: chromecast

I have a wifi network but will be turning off the internet source.
This is because I use the phone for all internet needs, apart from casting.
Therefore how can I cast to the TV which has the chromecast dongle set up on my wireless network ~ no internet.

Comment: Have you tried the app Localcast? I haven't tried it myself. (It is ad supported). https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stefanpledl.localcast&hl=sv&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dchromecast+stream+directly&pcampaignid=APPU_1_1zLZWaiHDKqR6ATl7YuYAw